# Image Included: Blazor sometimes loses its styling and navbar. I can't figure out why

Tags: c#, bootstrap-4, blazor, blazor-server-side

Here's a link to what it looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7UUU.jpg

This happens to me every once in awhile, and I can't figure out how to fix it.  Even if delete the project, download the previously working version from GitHub, it still will do this.

If I am to create a new project, the problem is not there.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

If you inspect the page the bootstrap link should be in the header portion above the navbar inside the _Host.cshtml. This is the layout of your application. I used the link provided and was able to render the page. Never place `<script>` tags inside the header... by standard these should go above the `</body>`.

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">`

I would also add the script tags just above the `</body>` portion.

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

Comment: no luck with the bootstrap, still broken.  Cleared my cache, uninstalled and reinstalled visual studio, deleted and redownloaded my file from git.  im at a loss.

Comment: if you inspect with developer tools do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: No, there aren’t any errors.  I’ve had this happen before, and I the only way I was able to fix it was to copy all my code to a new project. :(

Comment: The only other thing I could immediately think of is your bootstrap package is updating causing breaks in the code but I would think you would be seeing errors. Can you push to a git possibly so I can look?

Comment: That would be great!  I’ll make a public version of it shortly and send you the link!

Comment: Snoopdog, I created this github just for you.  I removed most of the app, as all you should need to see is the index page.  The repository should be public.  Thanks again for looking! https://github.com/TCrosmanDSI/ForSnoopDog

Comment: You have to create a new branch so I can pull the repository.... it seems like you need to make some changes inside _Host.cshtml.

Comment: I'm don't think thats the issue snoop, i even created a brand new blazor app that works, and replaced all of the existing html, javascript, and css files from the vanilla template.  still got the same problem.  Here is a new branch: https://github.com/TCrosmanDSI/ForSnoopDog/tree/NewBranch

Comment: I just pulled out the pages into another app.... did you try migrating this to .net 5 or was it created using .net 5

Comment: Wow now I'm really confused.  It should have been .net core 3.1.  When i change it back, it still has the same problem.

Comment: Ya that confused me too.... I’m not sure all the nuget packages will work with net5.... the Microsoft.Bulid package seems to be giving issues under this... and I believe that’s where the Layout comes from.... you could try to add the nav bar in each page as a break fix.... but you might work on reverting back to netcore

Comment: I tried reverting, and it didn’t work.  For now I copied all my code into a new project, and it works there.